# IOS5 Spanish character encoding

Tags: ios, character-encoding

I have a form with UItextfield and when entering this characters ( á é í ó ú ü ñ ) and send to a server via POST method, the content of this characters are transformed.

eg.:  this word "ñiña" wrote in the Textfield become on output as "√±i√±a"

```
 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&email=%@&password=%@&id_user=%@&iso_pais=%@&lugar=%@&titulo=%@&comment=%@&api_key=3333333",emailstring,passstring,idstring,locatedAtisocountry,cityLabel.text,title.text,description.text];

                NSLog(@"%@",post);
                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myweb.com/api/exp?format=json"]]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

The output of the post method is :

```
&email=username&password=5555&id_user=1032&iso_pais=PL&lugar=Madrid&titulo=√±i√±a&comment=&api_key=3333333
```

But the server side decodes the content of the key "titulo" as "nina" and should be "ñiña"

How can I fix this issue with this characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use percent escapes when passing characters thru the GET or POST parameters.

Use the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method for that.

Also don't use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` but rather `NSUTF8StringEncoding` if your server supports UTF8 (hopefully it does) and don't allow lossy convertion (that's the part in your code that transforms "ñ" to "n")

Answer (score 1):

I think it is safer to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` when you are trying to retain accent marks instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`.

You might need to update your server encoding since the two need to match.